# Cordova using wrong codesign

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to compile my app for release on the command line. It fails saying, "B106B71D657690A05D8511D6F46C64BAA37783C5: no identity found". Looking up through the output (`cordova compile --release`), i see:

```
Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: <me> (<a code>)"
Provisioning Profile: "<provisioning profile>"
                      (<Profile UUID>)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign B106B71D657690A05D8511D6F46C64BAA37783C5
```

The argument passed to `--sign` is not in `security find-identity` and in fact, I have no idea where it was found. My iPhone Developer account is in `security find-identity` but it is listed with a different number altogether.

How can I find what cordova is trying to use for the code signing identity here? Or how can i get it to use the correct code signing identity?